# How to sort to different arrays where each value is assigned to a value from another array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am trying to sort these two arrays. For example:
(array1) `[3,1,6,5]` and (array2) `[A1,A2,A3,A4]`.

I need to sort array one into ascending order and I already a sorting function to do this. However, 3 is assigned to A1, 1 is assigned to A2, 6 is assigned to A3 and 5 is assigned to A4. I need to re-arrange array 2 (so that array 1 is in ascending order) and array 2 has each element in the same position as its assigned element from array one.

So the answer to the example would be: `[1,3,5,6]` and `[A2,A1,A4,A3]`

Comment: read `sort` documentation...

Comment: try using second output argument of `sort` (which you get by sorting A1) in combination with A2.

Answer (score 1):

just read [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) documentation!

```
a=[3,1,6,5]
[b ix]=sort(a)


b =
 1     3     5     6

ix =
 2     1     4     3
```